# C# Selenium Spec Flow Tests runs on local PC on Visual Studio but not in Linux Docker Container - Invalid URI: The Authority/Host could not be parsed

Tags: docker, dockerfile

My test are running on Pc but not running on Linux Docker. Am I missing something important? Here is the error on Linux:

`Successfully built b8ec69d1cae8
Successfully tagged qa_CCmin:latest
abcd@5CG926281M:/mnt/c/IT/Ap/Supp/Adm$ docker run --network=host qa_adm:latest
        [ERROR] Object reference not set to an instance of an object
Invalid URI: The Authority/Host could not be parsed.
Test Run Failed.`

This is my docker file:

```
FROM ghha-docker.jfrog.io/qa_base_image:1
ENV DOTNET_RUNNING_IN_CONTAINER=true
#Copy sourcecode into image and do compilation
RUN mkdir /src
COPY QA/Adm/ /src
WORKDIR /src
RUN nuget restore
RUN msbuild Adm.sln

#Setup chromedriver and run smoke tests
WORKDIR /src/packages
RUN nuget install Microsoft.TestPlatform -Version 15.6.0 -Source http://www.nuget.org/api/v2/
RUN cp /src/packages/Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver.81.0.4044.6900/driver/linux64/chromedriver /usr/bin/chromedriver
RUN chmod +x /usr/bin/chromedriver
WORKDIR /src/Adm/bin/Debug
RUN cp /src/packages/SpecRun.Runner.3.2.22/tools/net45/TechTalk.SpecRun.Common.dll /src/Adm/bin/Debug/
CMD mono /src/packages/Microsoft.TestPlatform.15.6.0/tools/net451/Common7/IDE/Extensions/TestPlatform/vstest.console.exe Adm.dll /TestCaseFilter:TestCategory=smoke 2>&1 > /src/adm_testexecution.log || echo "There were failing tests!"
```

Answer (score 0):

Initially I was using .net 4.6.1 before after crating a new project using .net core 2.1 the same project started running perfectly.